# Getting Error for Excel to Table Conversion

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I just started learning Python and now I'm trying to integrate that with my GIS knowledge. As the title suggests, I'm attempting to convert an Excel sheet to a table but I keep getting errors, one which is wholly undecipherable to me and the other which seems to be suggesting that my file does not exist which, I know is incorrect since I copied it's location directly from it's properties.

Here is a screenshot of my environment. Please help if you can and thanks in advance.

[Environment/Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0p0L.png)

Comment: You are right but you also treated the input variable in the wrong way. Next time, make a text copy of the error message and also provide the code used to call it.

Comment: I have used this functionality often at work. Please see how I apply it.Happy to expound because I am trying to hone explanation of technical issues to average end users.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set, you put the workspace directory inside the filename variable so when arcpy handles it, it tries to acess a file that does not exist, in an unknown workspace.

Try this.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "J:\egis_work\dpcd\projects\SHARITA\Python\"
arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("Exceltest.xlsx", "Bookstorestable", "Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Arcpy uses the following syntax to convert [geodatabase tables to excel](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-excel.htm)
[image]

It is straight forward.

Example

Excel tables cannot be stored in the geodatabase. Most reasonable thing is to store them in the rootfolder in which the geodatabase with the table is. Say I want to convert [image: this geodatabase] table below into excel and save it in the root folder or in the folder in which the geodatabase is.

I will go as follows: I have put the explanations after the #.

```
import arcpy
import os
from datetime import datetime, date, time

# Set environment settings
in_table= r"C:\working\Sunderwood\Network Analyst\MarchDistances\Centroid.gdb\SunderwoodFirstArcpyTable"

#os.path.basename(in_table)

out_xls= os.path.basename(in_table)+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') # Here

#os.path.basename(in_table)- Gives the base name of pathname. In this case, it returns  the name table
# + is used in python to concatenate
# datetime.now()- gives todays date
# Converts todays date into a string in the format YYYMMDD
# Please add all the above statements and you notice you have a new file name which is the table you input plus todays date


#os.path.dirname() method in Python is used to get the directory name from the specified path
geodatabase = os.path.dirname(in_table)
# In this case, os.path.dirname(in_table)  gives us the geodatabase


# The The join() method takes all items in an iterable and joins them into one string
SaveInFolder= "\\".join(geodatabase.split('\\')[:-1])

# This case, I tell python take \ and join on the primary directory above which I have called geodatabase. However, I tell it to remove some characters. I will explain the split below.

# I use split method. The split() method splits a string into a list
#In the case above it splits into  ['W:\\working\\Sunderwood\\Network', 'Analyst\\MarchDistances\\Centroid.gdb']. However, that is not what I want. I want to remove "\\Centroid.gdb" so that I remain with the follwoing path ['W:\\working\\Sunderwood\\Network', 'Analyst\\MarchDistances']

#Before I tell arcpy to save, I have to specify the workspace in which it will save. So I now make my environment the SaveInFolder
arcpy.env.workspace =SaveInFolder

## Now I have to tell arcpy what I will call my newtable. I use os.path.join.This method concatenates various path components with exactly one directory separator (‘/’) following each non-empty part except the last path component
newtable = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, out_xls)

#In the above case it will give me "W:\working\Sunderwood\Network Analyst\MarchDistances\SunderwoodFirstArcpyTable20200402"

# You notice the newtable does not have an excel extension. I resort to + to concatenate .xls onto my path and make it "W:\working\Sunderwood\Network Analyst\MarchDistances\SunderwoodFirstArcpyTable20200402.xls"

table= newtable+".xls"

#Finally, I call the arcpy method and feed it with the required variables
# Execute TableToExcel
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(in_table, table)
print (table + "  " + " is now available")
```